# Periodically retrieving latest InfoTypes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I've just started out using the Google Cloud DLP library, and was wondering if there's a utility for retrieving the latest InfoType items without resorting to pulling down the JSON files from the API service. I.e. is there a built-in utility for this in the client Java library?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Google Cloud only provides the API. Keep in mind that in order to have more flexibility you have to pull the InfoType as they can change over the time.